# Can I swap weapons mid-attack?

Tags: hearthstone

A Paladin has a [Tirion Fordring](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/391-tirion-fordring) in play and a [Light's Justice](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/250-lights-justice) weapon equipped.

A Hunter has a [Knife Juggler](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/422-knife-juggler) in play and a [Snake Trap](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/210-snake-trap) secret up.

The Paladin starts attacking the Knife Juggler with Light's Justice triggering Snake Trap. The Knife Juggler starts juggling and deals fatal damage to Tirion Fordring.

**What happens next?**

Does the Paladin switch weapons to [Ashbringer](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/53-ashbringer) mid-attack and then hit the Knife Juggler with it? Does the attack cancel?

Comment: Really interesting scenario... I personally think that you'd attack with Light Bringer, then get Ashbringer, but that's purely speculation. You might try posting this on /r/hearthstone and see if anyone has actually run into this, or can set up the scenario with a friend.

Comment: If Hearthstone stack implementation works as the one in Magic The Gathering, the switch of weapon would happen before the hit since the stack should be cleared before it happens.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Hearthstones stack is not like Magic: The Gathering, especially concerning death and deathrattles. However, there is a separate 'start attack' phase and an 'attack' phase that probably allows the deathrattle of Tirion to proc.

Comment: Yes and that's because Hearthstone is, still, less complex than MtG and it seems (haven't studied all cards and effects) to use the stack for everything, meaning it is a lot easier to understand how and why things happen.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Hearthstone is less complex than Magic: The Gathering and probably always will be. Hearthstone does not use a stack for everything--deathrattles, for example, happen in the order they were played. That's not a stack, that's a queue!

Comment: It's just the order they go on the stack (Last in, first out... or last in play, first on the stack), not that they don't use the stack per se. And that is even disputed as a fact.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a video proof :
[Youtube](https://youtu.be/eX8Hmp8r1Q4?t=26s)

The video shows a Paladin attacking with a weapon into a Hunter's Explosive Trap while Tirion Fordring is at 2 health. The secret triggers, kills Tirion, the Paladin equips Ashbringer, and only then does the Paladin hit the Hunter, now using Ashbringer instead of the original weapon.

Result : You can change weapon mid-attack.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, you will damage with Ashbringer (no proof)

Events:

1. You start your attack
2. Snake Trap triggers
3. 3 times these events, one by one

   1. Snake appears
   2. Knife Juggler Triggers (Damage to target)
   3. Target's health is <=0? Then no longer can be targeted (unless it's the player) but no deathrattle triggered yet.
4. Deathrattle triggers from Tirion
5. Ashbringer replaces your current weapon
6. You damage Knife Juggler with Ashbringer
7. Your weapon loses 1 durabiliy

Answer (score 1):

No video proof, but you attack with the Ashbringer:

http://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/2agove/i_had_an_interesting_reaction_with_a_paladins/

Answer (score 0):

Ben Brode says:

> [Nobody dies during an effect. (Poison Seeds is the only exception)](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/537682686446665730)

So, in theory you will finish the attack with Light's Justice and then Tirion will die and you will receive an Ashbringer.

Comment: When a secret is revealed, its effect will take place. Then that effect is resolved(we can now all die), the 3 snakes from the trap comes into play, triggering the Jungler's ability. Tirion dies before the attack is rsolved (or even started). Similar on how a explosive trap can kill before the attack is resolved.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau it makes sense... I think we need some experimentation

Comment: @ClickOk I concur with JonathanDrapeau, attacking is not an 'effect' in the same way that the effect of the Sabotage spell is an 'effect'. Even if you are correct in the outcome, this explanation isn't relevant.